# junit how would I assert that my method returns a specific array

Tags: java, junit, bluej

I have a method that returns the array Sighting[].  In my unit test, there should be one element (element1) at index[0].

My question is, how do I build my statement to reflect this ? I need to assert that the array returned by my getMostOfSpecies method  contains element1 at the first index value.

my (failing) test looks like this

```
@Test
public void getMostOfSpeciesTest()
{
    try {
        birdList1.remember(sighting5);
        birdList1.remember(sighting6);
        birdList1.remember(sighting7);
        birdList1.remember(sighting8);
        assertEquals(birdList1.getMostOfSpecies("SOBI"), Sighting[???what to put here???]);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        fail("Failed" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried `Arrays.equals()` [1]? Make sure you override the equals()-method of your Sighting class as well.

```
assertTrue( Arrays.equals(birdList1.getMostOfSpecies("SOBI"), yourSightingArray);
```

[1] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

Edit:

If you need to check if the array contains one particular object you might be interested in `Arrays.binarySearch()` [2] or in `Arrays.asList()` in conjunction with List's contains()-method. So your assert-statement should look like

```
assertTrue( Arrays.binarySearch(birdList1.getMostOfSpecies("SOBI"), theElementYouExpect) >= 0);
```

[2] https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch(java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: andd,  my method returns an array.  I need to test that it contains a specific element.

Comment: Sorry, the title of your question is misleading "returns a specific array"... but you can use Arrays.binarySearch in your case, I think this is what you are looking for. I will edit my answer.